# Solving HCAPTCHA with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I've been trying for a week now to solve hcaptcha with selenium, but everytime when I try to submit is says captcha not solved

```
captchaSolution = get_Task()
print(f"Captcha solution: {captchaSolution}")
driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementsByName('h-captcha-response')[0].value = '{captchaSolution}';")
driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementsByName('g-recaptcha-response')[0].value = '{captchaSolution}';")
```

It changes the hcaptcha value with the solution but it doesn't say that it's solved, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: What is your question, and why do you you think this is enough information for someone to answer it?

Comment: I edited it a bit, Don't know what more I can say about it

Comment: You realize that the point of captchas is to make sure they're not solved by robots, right?

Comment: Yes, but captcha solvers exist so I don't get why that's an issue, so much people solve captcha's on a daily using bots.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking how to bypass a common website security feature.

Comment: @joanis  Why do you believe this is not a valid question. If its not valid then lets vote to remove all the other questions asked about hcaptcha and recaptcha on this site.

Comment: @hdsouza Well, I always vote to close such questions, but I guess my opinion is not a consensus opinion... Maybe I'll stop bothering with such votes. But I'm still not confortable keeping questions here about bypassing security measures, even if such bypassers exit in software.